# Segmentation default C++ que depende del número de partículas

Tags: c++

He leído una y otra vez mi código y no sé qué pasa. En cuanto `N` se pasa de unos 580-590, ya da segmentation default. Viendo tantas y tantas preguntas de segmentation faults, me da hasta vergüenza preguntar, pero no veo nada que pueda explicarme qué me sucede (o yo no consigo percatarme).

Por ejemplo, `N=590`, me da problemas con la función "fuerzas". Y por ejemplo, `N=1600`, también da problemas pero aparentemente con la función "potenciales". Empleo "Anjuta" para compilar, pero con "Codeblocks" también falla.

Los parallel for se pueden quitar (quizás uso muchos, pero no tienen la culpa, que los puse después) y tampoco me va sin ellos ...

Este es el código:

```
/*
 * SIMULACIÓN DE PARTÍCULAS CLÁSICAS NO RELATIVISTAS 
 * INTERACTUANTES BAJO UN POTENCIAL DE LÉNARD JONES 

 * Fecha: lunes 7 de noviembre de 2016

 * Unidades y constantes, todas unitarias:

 * - En el potencial de Lénard-Jones, la energía "epsilon" y  
 *   la separación "sigma" las considero de valor unidad "1".
 * - La masa individual de las partículas (moléculas de masa 
 *   "m") la considero de valor unidad "1".
 * - La constante de Stephan-Boltzmann "kB" también la consi-
 *   dero de valor unidad "1".

 *   El cambio a otro sistema de unidades se deduce mediante
 *   análisis dimensional.

 * La celda unidad es un cubo de lado L.

*/


#include <iostream>             // genérico
#include <cmath>                // pow
#include <cstdlib>              // srand, rand
#include <fstream>              // escritura de archivos
#include <omp.h>                // cálculo paralelo

// Constantes que impongo

const int N=1600;               // número de partículas soporta 583-590
//590 da error en sgm fault en fzas, 1600 en potencial
const int L=10;                 // arista
const int T0=1;                 // Temperatura que quiero
const double dt=0.002;          // Paso temporal
const double tmax=4;            // Tiempo físico máximo a simular
const double rcut=2.5;          // Distancia donde desprecio interación

// Magnitudes que, en consecuencia, quedan fijadas colateralmente

const int DIVS=int(tmax/dt)+1;  // Número de divisiones del tiempo
const double ucut=4*pow(rcut,-6)*(pow(rcut,-6)-1);
                                // Potencial de corte

// Funciones que predeclaro y que definiré tras main()

void promedio(double v[N][3], double V[3]);
void termalizador(double v[N][3], double T);
void integrador(double xm[N][3], double x[N][3], double v[N][3],
                double f[N][3], double paso);
void cinetica(double v[N][3], double K[DIVS][2], int c);
void potencial(double x[N][3], double U[DIVS][2], int C);
void fuerzas(double x[][3], double f[][3]);

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// 1. Posiciones iniciales //MAL
    double x[N][3];
    //ambito de bloque comienza
    {
    int NG=pow(ceil(pow(N,double(1)/double(3))),3); //bien
    double sep=L*pow(NG,double(-1)/double(3)); //bien
    double lim=L-sep; //bien
    int M=pow(NG,double(1)/double(3));
    int c=0; //bien

    // a cero todo x[N][3]
    for (int a1=0; a1<=M; a1++)
    {
        for (int a2=0; a2<=M; a2++)
        {
            for (int a3=0; a3<=M; a3++)
            {
                if (c<N)
                {
                    x[c][0]=0;      //bien
                    x[c][1]=0;      //bien
                    x[c][2]=0;      //bien
                    c++;            //bien
                }
                else
                {
                    break;          //bien
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //ahora lo actualizo como toca
    c=0;
    for (int a1=0; a1<=M; a1++)
    {
        for (int a2=0; a2<=M; a2++)
        {
            for (int a3=0; a3<=M; a3++)
            {
                if (c<N)
                {
                    x[c][0]=a1*sep; //bien
                    x[c][1]=a2*sep; //bien
                    x[c][2]=a3*sep; //bien
                    c++;            //bien
                }
                else
                {
                    break;          //bien
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Hello world!" << " "<<"N="<<N<<" "<< "NG="<< NG<<endl;
    cout << "sep="<<sep<<" "<<"lim="<<lim<<"c="<<c<<endl;
    cout << "M="<<M<<endl;
    }
    //ambito de bloque termina

    ofstream xinic;
    xinic.open("posicionesiniciales.txt");
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        xinic << c << " "<< x[c][0]<< " "<<x[c][1]<< " "<<x[c][2]<< endl;
    }
    xinic.close();
    //bien

// 2. Velocidades iniciales sin ajustar
    double v[N][3];
    srand(1);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3;coord++)
        {
            v[c][coord]=(double (rand() %10000)-5000)/5000;
        }
    }

    ofstream vinic;
    vinic.open("velocidadesinicialessin.txt");
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        vinic << c << " "<< v[c][0]<< " "<<v[c][1]<< " "<<v[c][2]<< endl;
    }
    vinic.close();
    //bien

// 3. Velocidades iniciales ajustadas sin momento neto
    double V[3]={0,0,0};
    promedio(v,V);
    cout << "V promedio="<<V[0]<<" "<<V[1]<<" "<<V[2]<<endl;
    //bien

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3;coord++)
        {
            v[c][coord]+=-V[coord];
        }
    }

    ofstream vinic2;
    vinic2.open("velocidadesinicialesMOM.txt");
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        vinic2 << c << " "<< v[c][0]<< " "<<v[c][1]<< " "<<v[c][2]<< endl;
    }
    vinic2.close();
    //bien

// 4. Velocidades iniciales ajustadas sin momento neto y a temperatura T0

    termalizador(v,double(T0));

    ofstream vinic3;
    vinic3.open("velocidadesinicialesMOMyT.txt");
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        vinic3 << c << " "<< v[c][0]<< " "<<v[c][1]<< " "<<v[c][2]<< endl;
    }
    vinic3.close();

// 5. Posiciones iniciales previas a las dadas
    double xm[N][3]; //paralelizable creo, escribir su for inicial

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            xm[c][coord]=x[c][coord]-v[c][coord]*dt;
        }
    }

    ofstream xminic;
    xminic.open("posicionesinicialesm.txt");
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        xminic << c << " "<< xm[c][0]<< " "<<xm[c][1]<< " "<<xm[c][2]<< endl;
    }
    xminic.close();

// 6. Declaración de fuerzas, energías y temperatura

    double K[DIVS][2];          // Energía cinética promedio por partícula
    double U[DIVS][2];          // Energía potencial promedio por partícula
    double H[DIVS][2];          // Energía total promedio por partícula
    double T[DIVS][2];          // Temperatura promedio
    // tienen en común esta estructura: [contador, [tiempo, valor]]

    double f[N][3];             // Fuerza total sobre la partícula N

// 7. Obtención de las energías y temperatura en el tiempo e integración de las 
// ecuaciones de movimiento

    double t;
    for (int c=0; c<DIVS; c++)
    {
        t=c*dt;                     // Instante de tiempo

        K[c][0]=t;                  // Instante de tiempo para K
        cinetica(v,K,c);            // Energía cinética para K, en K[c][1]
        //bien

        U[c][0]=t;                  // Instante de tiempo para U
        potencial(x,U,c);           // Potencial para U, en U[c][1]
        // bien

        H[c][0]=t;                  // Instante de tiempo para H
        H[c][1]=K[c][1]+U[c][1];    // Energía total para H
        //bien

        T[c][0]=t;                  // Instante de tiempo para T
        T[c][1]=K[c][1]*2/3;
        //bien

        fuerzas(x,f);               // Fuerzas en el instante de tiempo t
        //bien ?

        integrador(xm, x, v, f, dt); // Integración como tal
    }

    ofstream poten;
    ofstream enerc;
    ofstream enert;
    ofstream temper;
    ofstream fzas;
    enerc.open("enercin.txt");
    for (int c=0; c<DIVS; c++)
    {
        enerc << c << " "<< K[c][0] << " "<< K[c][1]<< endl;
    }
    enerc.close();
    poten.open("energpotencial.txt");
    for (int c=0; c<DIVS; c++)
    {
        poten << c << " "<< U[c][0] << " "<< U[c][1]<< endl;
    }
    poten.close();
    enert.open("energtotal.txt");
    for (int c=0; c<DIVS; c++)
    {
        enert << c << " "<< H[c][0] << " "<< H[c][1]<< endl;
    }
    enert.close();
    temper.open("temperatura.txt");
    for (int c=0; c<DIVS; c++)
    {
        temper << c << " "<< T[c][0] << " "<< T[c][1]<< endl;
    }
    temper.close();

    cout << "DIVS="<<DIVS<<" "<<"ucut="<<ucut<<endl;
    cout << "¡Ole!" <<endl;
    return 0;
}

/*  -----------------------
    FUNCIONES PREDECLARADAS
    ----------------------- */

void promedio(double v[N][3], double V[3])
{
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++) //paralelizable?
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3;coord++)
        {
            V[coord]+=v[c][coord]/N;
        }
    }
}//bien

void termalizador(double v[N][3], double T)
{
    double v2[N][3]; //paralelizable
    // A cero todo
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            v2[c][coord]=0;
        }
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            v2[c][coord]=v[c][coord]*v[c][coord];
        }
    }
    double sumv2[3]={0,0,0}; //paralelizable

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            sumv2[coord]+=v2[c][coord];
        }
    }

    double V2=0; //paralelizable pero es pequeño, luego sería contraproducente
    for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            V2+=sumv2[coord];
        }
    V2=V2/N;

    //hallar constante y aplicarla
    double k=sqrt(3*T/V2);
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            v[c][coord]=k*v[c][coord];
        }
    }
}//bien

void integrador(double xm[N][3], double x[N][3], double v[N][3],
                double f[N][3], double paso)
{
    double xx=0;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            xx=2*x[c][coord]-xm[c][coord]+f[c][coord]*paso*paso;
            v[c][coord]=(xx-xm[c][coord])/2/paso;
            xm[c][coord]=x[c][coord];
            x[c][coord]=xx;
        }
    }
} // bien

void cinetica(double v[N][3], double K[DIVS][2], int C)
{
    double v2[N][3]; 
    // A cero todo, paralelizable
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++) 
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            v2[c][coord]=0;
        }
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            v2[c][coord]=v[c][coord]*v[c][coord];
        }
    }

    double sumv2=0; //paralelizable

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            sumv2+=v2[c][coord];
        }
    }
    K[C][1]=0.5*sumv2/N;
} //bien

void potencial(double x[N][3], double U[DIVS][2], int C)
{
    double u[N][N];
    // a cero todo, paralelizable
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int a=0; a<N; a++)
    {
        for (int b=0; b<N; b++)
        {
            u[a][b]=0;
        }
    }

    double R6=0;
    double resta=0;
    U[C][1]=0;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int a=0; a<N; a++) //paralelizable
    {
        for (int b=0; b<N; b++) //paralelizable
        {
            if (a==b)
            {
                u[a][b]=0;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++) //paralelizable, pero no.
                {
                    resta=x[b][coord]-x[a][coord];
                    resta=resta-L*round(resta/L);
                    R6+=pow(resta,2);
                }
                if (R6<rcut*rcut)
                {                   
                    R6=pow(R6,-3);
                    u[a][b]=0.5*(-ucut+4*R6*(R6-1));    // el 0.5 es porque
                                        // u[a][b]=u[b][a]
                }
                else
                {
                    u[a][b]=0;                          // desprecio interac.
                }
                R6=0;
                U[C][1]+=u[a][b];
            }
        }
    }
    U[C][1]=U[C][1]/N;
}

void fuerzas(double x[][3], double f[][3])
{
    //purgo las fuerzas totales sobre "a"
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int a=0; a<N; a++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            f[a][coord]=0;
        }
    }

    // fuerzas individuales
    double ff[N][N][3];
    // a cero todo, paralelizable

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int a=0; a<N; a++)
    {
        for (int b=0; b<N; b++)
        {
            for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
            {
                ff[a][b][coord]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    double R6=0;
    double R2=0;
    double resta[3]={0,0,0};

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int a=0; a<N; a++)
    {
        for (int b=0; b<N; b++)
        {
            if (a==b)
            {
                for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
                {
                    ff[a][b][coord]=0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++) //paralelizable, pero no
                {
                    resta[coord]=x[a][coord]-x[b][coord];
                    resta[coord]=resta[coord]-L*round(resta[coord]/L);
                    R2+=pow(resta[coord],2);
                }
                if (R2<rcut*rcut)
                {
                    R2=1/R2;
                    R6=pow(R2,3);
                    for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
                    {
                        ff[a][b][coord]=48*resta[coord]*R2*R6*(R6-0.5);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
                    {
                        ff[a][b][coord]=0;
                    }
                }
            }
            R2=0;
        }
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int a=0; a<N; a++)
    {
        for (int b=0; b<N; b++)
        {
            for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
            {
                f[a][coord]+=ff[a][b][coord];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ya recuperaste la autoría de tu pregunta, en caso de que quieras modificar algo o aceptar la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias por las ediciones y las gestiones. Veo mi código ahora y me doy cuenta de lo novato que era.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Has llenado la pila de tu proceso.

He visto que todos tus vectores los has declarado estáticamente, y la función `fuerzas` declara él solito un vector de `double[N][N][3]`, que para `N=590` ya son 12MiB. El valor para `N=1600` lo dejo como ejercicio al lector (`sizeof(double) == 12` normalmente).

No es un problema de RAM, sino de secciones de memoria: cada programa/proceso puede consumir tanta memoria como pueda direccionar tu SO. Si tu equipo es de 32-bits, teóricamente cualquier programa puede ocupar hasta 4GB de memoria (aunque luego el SO te quita 1 o 2GiB para uso propio), independientemente de cuánta RAM dispongas físicamente. Lo que no quepa en RAM, va a disco (memoria virtual).

El tema es que el SO, mientras que permite que la memoria dinámica crezca ilimitadamente (hasta esos 2-3 GiB máximos que puedes ocupar --para 32 bits), la memoria estática del programa, "la pila", suele estar limitada a 8 MiB.

¿Por qué estos límites para la pila? Pues por que la pila se usa constantemente y por tanto, hay menos fallos de caché, que hace que la pila tiende a quedarse en RAM, afectando a otros procesos (la RAM es compartida y limitada), a lo que hay que sumar que cada hilo del proceso crea su propia pila local, y de ahí estos límites para la pila de cada proceso. Actualmente en Linux son unos 8MiB. Las versiones actuales de Win no lo sé, pero creo que menores, y versiones antiguas (XP quizás?) tenían un límite de solo 1 MB. La memoria dinámica, por otro lado, no está limitada, salvo por las capacidades de direccionamiento de tu SO (y la memoria que te quita gratuitamente).

Cuando la pila se llena, se produce un *stack overflow* y tu programa recive la señal `SIGSEGV` (fallo de segmentación).

El resto de tus vectores, para `N = 1600` y `DIVS = 2000`, ocupan juntos unos 400KiB, así tu solución sería sustituir:

```
double ff[N][N][3];
```

por:

```
double (*ff)[N][3] = new double[N][N][3];

// cuando ya no vuelvas a utilizar `ff`
delete[] ff;
```

y no tendrías que cambiar nada más en el código, ni el resto de pila, y todo debería ejecutar sin problemas.

Si puedes utilizar C++11, lo tienes en una sola línea:

```
std::unique_ptr<double [][2][3]> ff(new double[5][2][3]);
```

Y no necesitas llamar a `delete`. Cuando `ff` salga de ámbito (bien porque acabe la función, bien porque se lanze una excepción), el destructor llama a `delete` del puntero interno. En tu caso, sin embargo, no se lanzarán excepciones a no ser que modifiques el código (tu código es fundamentalmente un programa en C con `stream`s).

La "técnica" para la que se diseñó `std::unique_ptr` se llama *RAII* (*Recuerse adquisition is initialization*), y es una manera de trabajar a la que hay que acostumbrarse y utilizar en cualquier circunstancia.

Fundamentalmente significa que si un objeto representa un recurso (cualquier cosa que no esté en la pila, y `ff` representa un vector dinámico), la vida del recurso debe coincidir con la vida de la variable que lo representa, y la vida acaba al salir de ámbito, bien sea por terminar el bloque, un `return` (o `break/continue` en bucles), terminar la sentencia actual si es un objeto temporal, o que se lance una excepción antes de que finalice su ámbito.

Comment: Muchas gracias, todo se solucionó empleando variables dinámicas.

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, agradecer a Peregring-lk [su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/32231). No me funcionaba todavía lo que me propusiste, pero me dejaste en el camino a seguir: **usar variables dinámicas**. Gracias, con eso en mente, ya después consulté el "Guide to scientific computing in C++" de Pitt y de Whiteley y he visto cómo hacer matrices de punteros multidimensionales (he llegado hasta un array `[N][N][3]` como quería).

Por fin lo tengo. Se evidencia que la temperatura que uno impone al principio termina por cambiar a un estado fluctuante con otros valores. Es normal, uno impone una red cristalina como posiciones iniciales, y ese es un estado muy raro para un fluido ;)

Mi solución:

```
/*
 * SIMULACIÓN DE PARTÍCULAS CLÁSICAS NO RELATIVISTAS 
 * INTERACTUANTES BAJO UN POTENCIAL DE LÉNARD JONES 

 * Autor: Manuel Martín Bravo
 * Fecha: martes 8 de noviembre de 2016

 * Unidades y constantes, todas unitarias:

 * - En el potencial de Lénard-Jones, la energía "epsilon" y  
 *   la separación "sigma" las considero de valor unidad "1".
 * - La masa individual de las partículas (moléculas de masa 
 *   "m") la considero de valor unidad "1".
 * - La constante de Stephan-Boltzmann "kB" también la consi-
 *   dero de valor unidad "1".

 *   El cambio a otro sistema de unidades se deduce mediante
 *   análisis dimensional.

 *   Se integran las ecuaciones de evolución con el método 
 *   Verlet de velocidades.

 *   La celda unidad es un cubo 3D de lado L.

*/

#include <iostream>             // genérico
#include <cmath>                // pow
#include <cstdlib>              // srand, rand
#include <fstream>              // escritura de archivos
#include <omp.h>                // cálculo paralelo
#include <time.h>               // medir tiempo de ejecución

// Constantes que impongo

const int N=1000;               // número de partículas 1000 van, 3.87 mins
const int L=10;                 // arista
const int T0=1;                 // Temperatura que quiero
const double dt=0.002;          // Paso temporal
const double tmax=4;            // Tiempo físico máximo a simular
const double rcut=2.5;          // Distancia donde desprecio interación

// Magnitudes que, en consecuencia, quedan fijadas colateralmente

const int DIVS=int(tmax/dt)+1;  // Número de divisiones del tiempo
const double ucut=4*pow(rcut,-6)*(pow(rcut,-6)-1);
                                // Potencial en el corte

// Funciones que predeclaro y que definiré tras main()

void promedio(double** v, double V[3]);
void termalizador(double** v, double T);
void integrador(double** xm, double** x, double** v,
                double** f, double paso);
void cinetica(double** v, double& K);
void potencial(double** x, double& U, double** u);
void fuerzas(double** x, double** f, double*** ff);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    clock_t start, end;                 // declaro contadores de tiempo de ejec.
    start=clock();                      // tiempo de ejecución inicial
// 1. Posiciones iniciales
    double** x;
    x=new double* [N];
    for (int a=0; a<N; a++)
    {
        x[a]=new double [3];
    }

    // Ámbito de bloque comienza
    {
    int NG=pow(ceil(pow(N,double(1)/double(3))),3); //bien
    double sep=L*pow(NG,double(-1)/double(3)); //bien
    double lim=L-sep; //bien
    int M=pow(NG,double(1)/double(3));
    int c=0; //bien

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int a1=0; a1<=M; a1++)
    {
        for (int a2=0; a2<=M; a2++)
        {
            for (int a3=0; a3<=M; a3++)
            {
                if (c<N)
                {
                    x[c][0]=a1*sep; //bien
                    x[c][1]=a2*sep; //bien
                    x[c][2]=a3*sep; //bien
                    c++;            //bien
                }
                else
                {
                    break;          //bien
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "N="<<N<<" NG="<< NG<<endl;
    cout << "sep="<<sep<<" "<<"lim="<<lim<<" c= "<<c<<endl;
    cout << "M="<<M<<endl;
    }
    //ambito de bloque termina

    ofstream xinic;
    xinic.open("posicionesiniciales.txt");
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        xinic << c << " "<< x[c][0]<< " "<<x[c][1]<< " "<<x[c][2]<< endl;
    }
    xinic.close();
    //bien

// 2. Velocidades iniciales sin ajustar
    double** v;
    v=new double* [N];
    for (int a=0; a<N; a++)
    {
        v[a]=new double [3];
    }
    srand(1);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3;coord++)
        {
            v[c][coord]=(double (rand() %10000)-5000)/5000;
        }
    }

    ofstream vinic;
    vinic.open("velocidadesinicialessin.txt");
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        vinic << c << " "<< v[c][0]<< " "<<v[c][1]<< " "<<v[c][2]<< endl;
    }
    vinic.close();
    //bien

// 3. Velocidades iniciales ajustadas sin momento neto
    double V[3]={0,0,0};
    promedio(v,V);
    cout << "V promedio="<<V[0]<<" "<<V[1]<<" "<<V[2]<<endl;
    //bien

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3;coord++)
        {
            v[c][coord]+=-V[coord];
        }
    }

    ofstream vinic2;
    vinic2.open("velocidadesinicialesMOM.txt");
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        vinic2 << c << " "<< v[c][0]<< " "<<v[c][1]<< " "<<v[c][2]<< endl;
    }
    vinic2.close();
    //bien

// 4. Velocidades iniciales ajustadas sin momento neto y a temperatura T0

    termalizador(v,double(T0));

    ofstream vinic3;
    vinic3.open("velocidadesinicialesMOMyT.txt");
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        vinic3 << c << " "<< v[c][0]<< " "<<v[c][1]<< " "<<v[c][2]<< endl;
    }
    vinic3.close();

    cout <<"Miro por curiosidad v[12][2]= "<<v[12][2]<<endl;

// 5. Posiciones iniciales previas a las dadas
    double** xm;
    xm=new double* [N];
    for (int a=0; a<N; a++)
    {
        xm[a]=new double [3];
    }
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            xm[c][coord]=x[c][coord]-v[c][coord]*dt;
        }
    }

    ofstream xminic;
    xminic.open("posicionesinicialesm.txt");
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        xminic << c << " "<< xm[c][0]<< " "<<xm[c][1]<< " "<<xm[c][2]<< endl;
    }
    xminic.close();

// 6. Declaración de energías y temperatura

    double K;                   // Energía cinética promedio por partícula
    double U;                   // Energía potencial promedio por partícula
    double H;                   // Energía total promedio por partícula
    double T;                   // Temperatura promedio por partícula

    double** u;
    u = new double* [N];    
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int a=0; a<N; a++)
    {
        u[a]= new double [N];
    }

    // fuerza de la partícula "b" sobre "a"
    double*** ff;
    ff = new double** [N];
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int a=0; a<N; a++)
    {
        ff[a]=new double* [N];
        for (int b=0; b<N; b++)
        {
            ff[a][b]=new double [3];
        }
    }       

    double** f; // Fuerza total sobre la partícula "a", como double f[N][3];
    f=new double* [N];
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int a=0; a<N; a++)
    {
        f[a]=new double [3];
    }

// 7. Obtención de las energías y temperatura en el tiempo e integración de las 
// ecuaciones de movimiento

    double t;
    ofstream poten;
    ofstream enerc;
    ofstream enert;
    ofstream temper;
    enerc.open("enercin.txt");
    poten.open("energpotencial.txt");
    enert.open("energtotal.txt");
    temper.open("temperatura.txt");

    for (int c=0; c<DIVS; c++)
    {
        t=c*dt;                     // Instante de tiempo
        cout <<"t= "<<t;

        cinetica(v,K);          // Energía cinética para K, en K[c][1]
        enerc << t << " "<< K<< endl;
        cout << "\t" << "K= "<< K;
        //bien


        potencial(x,U,u);           // Potencial para U, en U[c][1]
        poten << t << " "<< U<< endl;
        cout << "\t" << "U= "<< U;

        H=K+U;              // Energía total para H
        enert << t << " "<< H<< endl;
        cout << "\t" << "H= "<< H;
    //bien

        T=K*2/3;            //  Temperatura media
        temper << t << " "<< T<< endl;
        cout << "\t" << "T= "<< T<<endl;
        //bien

        fuerzas(x,f,ff);                // Fuerzas en el instante de tiempo t
        //bien

        integrador(xm, x, v, f, dt); // Integración como tal
        //bien
    }
    enerc.close();
    poten.close();
    enert.close();
    temper.close();

    // eliminar *** ff
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            delete[] ff[i][j];
        }
    }
    delete[] ff;

    // eliminar v x xm f como **
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int a=0; a<N; a++)
    {
        delete[] f[a];
        delete[] x[a];
        delete[] xm[a];
        delete[] v[a];
    }
    delete[] f;
    delete[] x;
    delete[] xm;
    delete[] v;
    end=clock();                        // tiempo de ejecución final

    cout << "DIVS="<<DIVS<<" "<<"ucut="<<ucut<<endl;
    cout <<"Por curiosidad, miro si ha cambiado v[12][2]= "<<v[12][2]<<endl;
    cout << "¡Ole! He tardado en minutos ";
    cout << (float) (end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC/60 <<endl;
    return 0;
}   

/*  -----------------------
    FUNCIONES PREDECLARADAS
    ----------------------- */

void promedio(double** v, double V[3])
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3;coord++)
        {
            V[coord]+=v[c][coord]/N;
        }
    }
}//bien

void termalizador(double** v, double T)
{
    double v2[N][3];

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            v2[c][coord]=v[c][coord]*v[c][coord];
        }
    }
    double sumv2[3]={0,0,0};

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            sumv2[coord]+=v2[c][coord];
        }
    }

    double V2=0; //paralelizable pero es pequeño
    for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            V2+=sumv2[coord];
        }
    V2=V2/N;

    //hallar constante de termalización y aplicarla
    double k=sqrt(3*T/V2);
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            v[c][coord]=k*v[c][coord];
        }
    }
}//bien

void integrador(double** xm, double** x, double** v,
                double** f, double paso)
{
    double* xx;
    xx=new double [1];

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            xx[1]=2*x[c][coord]-xm[c][coord]+f[c][coord]*paso*paso;
            v[c][coord]=(xx[1]-xm[c][coord])/2/paso;
            xm[c][coord]=x[c][coord];
            x[c][coord]=xx[1];
        }
    }
    delete[] xx;
} // bien

void cinetica(double** v, double& K)
{
    double sumv2=0;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            sumv2+=v[c][coord]*v[c][coord];
        }
    }
    K=0.5*sumv2/N;
} //bien

void potencial(double** x, double& U, double** u)
{
    double R6=0;
    double resta=0;
    U=0;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int a=0; a<N; a++) 
    {
        for (int b=a+1; b<N; b++) //paralelizable
        {
            for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++) //paralelizable, pero pequeño
            {
                resta=x[b][coord]-x[a][coord];
                resta=resta-L*round(resta/L);
                R6+=pow(resta,2);
            }
            if (R6<rcut*rcut)
            {                   
                R6=pow(R6,-3);
                u[a][b]=-ucut+4*R6*(R6-1);
            }
            else
            {
                u[a][b]=0;                          // desprecio interac.
            }
            R6=0;
            U+=u[a][b];
        }
    }
    U=U/N;
}// bien

void fuerzas(double** x, double** f, double*** ff)
{
    //purgo las fuerzas totales sobre "a"
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int a=0; a<N; a++)
    {
        for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
        {
            f[a][coord]=0;
        }
    }

    double R6=0;
    double R2=0;
    double resta[3]={0,0,0};

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int a=0; a<N; a++)
    {
        for (int b=0; b<N; b++)
        {
            if (a!=b)
            {
                for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++) //paralelizable, pero no
                {
                    resta[coord]=x[a][coord]-x[b][coord];
                    resta[coord]=resta[coord]-L*round(resta[coord]/L);
                    R2+=pow(resta[coord],2);
                }
                if (R2<rcut*rcut)
                {
                    R2=1/R2;
                    R6=pow(R2,3);
                    for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
                    {
                        ff[a][b][coord]=48*resta[coord]*R2*R6*(R6-0.5);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
                    {
                        ff[a][b][coord]=0;
                    }
                }
                for (int coord=0; coord<3; coord++)
                {
                    f[a][coord]+=ff[a][b][coord];
                }
            }
            R2=0;
        }
    }
} // bien
```

Comment: Excelente consejo, me vendrá muy bien para responder o preguntar más adelante. Tomo nota: 1º pegar, 2º seleccionar, 3º {} ó Ctrl+K.